# Why does my program crash if I don't give command line arguments to it?

Tags: c++, command-line, crash, command-line-arguments

I made a simple test program to play around with C++11 threads.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void tee(int civ)
{
    for(int loop=0; loop<19; loop++, civ++)
    {
        civ = civ%19;
        cout << loop << "\t" << civ << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(300));
    }
}

void koot()
{
    while(true)
    {
        cout << ":) ";
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(300));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    thread saie(tee, atoi(argv[1])),
        kamaa(koot);
    saie.join();
    kamaa.join();

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine as long as I supply command line arguments, but if I don't, it crashes.
How can this be solved?
I tried checking the argument count, and if they existed, to no avail.

EDIT: I had to add this line:

```
if(argc < 2) return 1;
```

Comment: You are using `agv[1]`, which will be `NULL` if no command-line arguments are given. How did you do the checking?

Comment: Because `argv[1]` will be `NULL`?

Comment: Um... Because you're using `argv[1]` in your call to `saie`, and if you don't provide it it's NULL?

Comment: Why will it be `NULL`, guys? Seems to me that its value, such as it is, will be completely unspecified, and attempting to access it will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: OK, because `[C++11: 3.6.1/2]` says: `The value of argv[argc]
shall be 0.`. Note then, OP, that this _does not mean_ that `argv[2]` and so on will also be `NULL`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It crashes because you are accessing

```
argv[1]
```

which would hold a command line argument (other than the program's name) if there was one. You should check whether `argc` is greater than 1. Why greater than 1? Because the first command line argument is the name of the program itself. So `argc` is always greater than `0`. And indexing starts at `0`. So if `argc == 1`, only `argv[0]` is valid.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // no need to check argc for argv[0]
  std::cout << argc << " " << argv[0] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I needed this: if(argc < 2) return 1;

Answer (score 4):

`argv[1]` is null, causing a crash in the call to `atoi()`. Note that array indices in C++ are zero-based!

Answer (score 3):

because you don't check if `argc > 1` and you try to access `argv[1]`

way to solve this is first check if `argc > 1` and then access argv[1].

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if(argc > 1){
    thread saie(tee, atoi(argv[1])),
        kamaa(koot);
    saie.join();
    kamaa.join();
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Points to remember:

1. `argc` is by default 1. This is the argument counter that holds the no. of arguments passed to the program. By default, its 1 because the program gets the executable's name(and path)
2. `argv` holds the array of NULL terminated character arrays(or strings). `argv[0]` will always hold the name of the executable.
3. never assume user will always enter the arguments. and always do a bounds check while accessing `argv` or any array in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code instead:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2) {   cout<<"No command line arguments found\n Aborting!\n"; return 1;}
    else         {   thread saie(tee, atoi(argv[1])),kamaa(koot);}
    saie.join();
    kamaa.join();

    return 0;
}
```

You are trying to access a command line argument argv[1] which is not present. It is always better to check if the command line argument exists or not.

Comment: argc is always equal to or greater than 1

Comment: typo.. should've been argc < 2